# Regularity of Dirac measure on Baire sets

Tags: gn.general-topology, real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.
Define the Baire sets in $X$, denoted by $\mathcal Ba(X)$, 
to be the smallest $\sigma$-algebra that contains all compact $G_\delta$ subsets of $X$.
Let $x \in X$. Define the Dirac measure $\delta_x$ on $\mathcal Ba(X)$ by $\delta_x(E)$ = 1 if $x \in E$ and 0 otherwise.
Must Dirac measure be regular on the Baire sets?

Comment: Cross posted from MSE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1103444/regularity-of-dirac-measure-on-baire-sets

Comment: $\{x\}$ may not be a $G_\delta$.

Comment: So the definition of "regular" here should be: for each Baire set $A \subset X$ and each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an open Baire set $U$ and a compact Baire set $K$ with $K \subset A \subset U$ and $\mu(U \setminus K) < \epsilon$. And the problem with @ChristianRemling's suggestion is that $\{x\}$, though compact, may not be Baire.  Is that right?

Comment: In other words, to address @ChristianRemling's comment, if $\{x\}$ is not Baire (which can happen as in $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ then $\delta(\{x\})$ and $\delta(X\setminus\{x\})$ are undefined.

Comment: Correct. The measure is defined only on the Baire sets. If $X$ is $\sigma$-compact, every Baire measure is regular. I also believe that every finite Baire measure is outer regular.

Comment: This question should be closed because it has received a satisfactory answer on math.SE

Comment: Fine with me to close it here now. I posted it here originally only because I had received no response on math.SE after three days.